# behavior of "this" in NodeJS and JSC

Tags: javascript, this

I'm a little confusing with this code and the behavior of rules for binding this:

```
var a = 2;
var self = this;
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a); // node: undefined - jsc: 2
  console.log(self === this); // node: false - jsc: true
}
```

If I use node to run my code I get undefined and false, whilst with jsc (of course replace console.log with debug or create an alias) I get 2 and true. Why I get this behavior? Seems to be node run in strict mode.

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting `undefined` as default value `this` in JS is `window` which is not in available in node. So by default `this` is undefined

Comment: What is "JSC"??

Comment: A little google doesn't hurt :) [JSC](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. NodeJS wrap my file.js in a function:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  ...myCode
})(exports, require, module, 'file.js', '/dir/name');
```

So var a = 2 isn't in the global scope in NodeJS, and why I dind't get a

> true

when I do

> self===true

.

**foo() is a plain normal function call**, so it determines that I'll get the global object bound to the this for that call, and in my global scope, a is undefined! I need to remove the keyword var to get a true global variable.